# IndexTemplate to assign alias to newly created index only

Tags: elasticsearch

So we are using time frame indexes that are created automatically using an index template.
The ideal situation now would be to have an alias, let's call it 'current', that points to the last index created.

The question then is if there's any way we can do this through the index template. I can see that you can specify aliases, but I want also to remove the bindings between previous indexes and this 'current' alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Curator tool to do it for you

That tool has an [`alias` command](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/alias.html) that you can use in conjunction with the `indices` subcommand in order to remove an alias on your old index.

```
curator alias --name current --remove indices oldindex
```

You can combine the above command with a cron that would kick in around the same time your index template gets into action to create the new time-based index.

Comment: It is also possible to create your own plugin that would do it. Some inspiration : https://github.com/bcoe/webhooks

Comment: Anything else you need regarding this issue?

Comment: Not really, didn't go the curator way since we didn't need an alias really (or needed enough to go down that route). Don't mind to accept it as answer since it's probably the best way to go in these cases.